# Is object existence distinct from object lifetime?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, terminology, object-lifetime

It may sound philosophical, but it isn't: in C++, can various (classes, scalars) objects *exist* outside of their *lifetime*? What is the existence of an object? What is the creation of an object? Is an object created when its lifetime starts?

(Edited for clarity: the question is not specifically about class types.)

I'm extremely confused and need someone to explain the terminology and basic concepts to me.

Note: Existing is the fact of being a thing. It's the most fundamental philosophical concept. It isn't an attribute of an object and I don't know nor do I care about the number of occurrences of the word "exist" in the standard text. Textbooks probably very rarely say that things "exist". I don't remember ever reading that numbers "exist" in registers or that expressions "exist" in the source code. Numbers fit in registers and the source code has expressions in it.

**If we can refer to an object, it means it exists. If a pointer points to an object, that object exists.**

Comment: @L.F. "_Can you provide an example to show how the word "exist" is used in the standard?_" How is that relevant? "_To explain exist, exist should exist_" No. Existence is the concept of being something. **Do you believe that existence is an attribute of an object?** Do you talk about non existing things? Anything, that is, **any idea we talk about exists, by definition**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best understood with [[intro.object]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object):

> An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]). An object occupies a region of storage in its period of construction ([class.cdtor]), throughout its lifetime, and in its period of destruction ([class.cdtor]).

The second sentence there answers your question. If an object is able to occupy a region of storage outside of the period described as "its lifetime" (like during its construction and destruction), then clearly an object must be able to *exist* outside of its lifetime.

Comment: "_The statement you quoted_" I quoted no statement.

Comment: I'm not interesting in automatic variables, but on objects where the duration of existence isn't as clear.

Comment: Which implies that `malloc(sizeof(plain_old_data_t))` never creates anything that meets the definition of a C++ object. One of the types guaranteed by the Standard to be trivially copyable with no padding bits or trap representations might be an even better example.

Comment: @Davislor: It doesn't "imply" anything; those are the *only* C++ constructs that create objects. `malloc` doesn't create *any objects* as far as the C++ standard is concerned. Or at least, as the standard currently stands; [there are plans to change that](wg21.link/P0593).

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, yeah, but will there ever be an implementation where `malloc()` requires placement `new` to work? I guess if you want to be absolutely and strictly compliant with C++17, and use memory obtained from a C-style allocator, that’s what you have to do.

Comment: @NicolBolas Now if you claim to take the std extremely seriously on what creates an object, do you also never use a string literal?

Answer (score -2):

An object in C++ is an abstract concept. To machine code, it's just a big virtual array of bytes.

The physical "object" is a bunch of bytes in memory that get allocated for some purpose, and are associated some functions that act on those bytes. The lifetime of that object is the time when those bytes are used for that object's purpose, to when they are no longer used. They still exist afterwards, but they're available to be used by some other object.

Comment: At the end they are only bytes in memory, but at the abstract level, they are more than that; and the abstract machine relies on that abstract semantic.

Comment: I'm too pedestrian to think like that. To me, lifetime isn't even part of the abstract machine, it's just an metric for static analyzers and such. 

On the abstract level, I'm gonna say the tree didn't make a sound if no one was around. The object didn't exist until the program initialized it, and it stopped existing after the program stopped caring about it. Life is easier this way.

Comment: The whole C++ standard seems to be built around lifetime, an ill defined concept...

Comment: That's fair. If only I had 198 swiss francs, I could just look it up.

Comment: In C++, to say an object exists means more than just bytes of memory allocated for it. The bytes may continue to exist, but the object does not.